# OpenCL convert MxN matrix to square matrix

Tags: c, matrix, opencl, gpgpu

I'm trying to convert a 3x2 matrix into a square matrix which is 4x4:

```
__kernel void padding(float* newM, int m, int n, int newlength)
{

}
```

The matrix "newM" is in row-major-order, m=3, n=2 and newlength=4.
The elements in newM are all compact to the front and the tail of the matrix is just 0's. 
My confusion is how can i shift the elements along without losing the subsequent values. I would create a local copy, but the matrices that i am dealing with are extremely large and do not fit into private memory.

Here's a 1 dimensional look:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] -> [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Heres a 2 dimensional look:

```
[1, 1, 1]    [1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1] -> [1, 1, 1, 0]
             [0, 0, 0, 0]
             [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How it actually looks in 2D:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]    [1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0] -> [1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]    [0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]    [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

All numbers I have used here are just for this examples, in reality I have random floats in the matrices and dimensions are beyond 2000x2000.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you definitely need to do this on the device, i.e. is it something that needs to happen only at the start of your program or something that you need to do many times?

Comment: I would like to do this on the GPU, doing this on the CPU creates a major bottleneck in my program. The point of my program is to multiply two matrices together. The matrices can be of arbitrary length. I've created a kernel which can multiply two square matrices together extremely fast. So what I'm trying to do is now convert the two input matrices to have the same dimensions and be square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, if your data is ordered row-wise:

```
__kernel void padding(float* newMa, float* oldMa, int oldR, int oldC, int N)
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int r = id/N;
    int c = id%N;
    float value = 0.0f;
    if(r < oldR || c < oldC) //Inside the old matrix size
        value = oldMa[r*oldR+oldC];
    newMa[id] = value ;
}
```

The new matrix size should hold enough space for the operation, that is "NxN".

I don't know if you are using this memory ordering. Could you provide how you expect the data to interface with your other kernels? As other answer says, you provably don't need another kernel for such an easy operation. You can also integrate this inside your other kernel.

Comment: The main goal of the entire program is to multiply two matrices together, I'm doing this using an optimised kernel, which I created. It runs extremely fast if the matrices are "NxN". So what I want to do is convert all input matrices to have Dimensions NxN where N is the biggest dimension out of the pair of matrices. What I'm currently doing to tackle this problem is reallocating the memory on the CPU side. Mapping this to VRAM. Now I want to add the padding, then continue executing the rest. Then remove the padding when done.
I think your way will work but may waste memory?

Comment: Yes, it will waste memory and GPU operations. You should modify the code of the kernel of NxN multiplication ir order to avoid the rows/cols that are not present in the lowest sized matrix. That way you will not waste memory at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do any math, and the only target is to interpret data in other way, you don't need any OpenCL here.

Reallocate memory and introduce new matrix row.